# how to make an async call to firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling to retrieve data from firebase. basically im creating a dating app and when a user "likes" someone, it should check the displayed users liked people array to see if the current user is in there and then "match" them if they are

I have this function:

```
  pullFromFirebase = (displayedUser) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + displayedUser.id + '/usersLiked/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        const users = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(function(key) {
          return snapshot.val()[key];
        })
      });
    })
  }
```

This function is working, coz when I console.log(users), I get the array of the people who are liked. however, when I call this function like so

```
 async checkForMatch (currentUser, displayedUser) {
    const likedUsers = await this.pullFromFirebase(displayedUser);
    console.log(likedUsers, 'likedUsers');
  }
```

nothing is being logged in the console? and when I take away the async stuff, the console.log just says it's pending. what have i done wrong or why cant i get the users displayed in my `checkformatch` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you never resolved your promise in `pullFromFirebase` method

checkout the code

```
pullFromFirebase = (displayedUser) => 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    {
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + displayedUser.id + '/usersLiked/').once('value').then(function (snapshot) 
        {
            const users = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(function (key) {
                return snapshot.val()[key];
            })

            resolve(users);  // <--- here is the fix
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: @TheWalrus happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have added a Promise there unnecessairily and your function returns a Promise which never resolves. `firebase.database` returns a Promise already but you also need to return the `users` you get within `.then()`:

```
pullFromFirebase = (displayedUser) => {
      return firebase.database().ref('users/' + displayedUser.id + '/usersLiked/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        const users = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(function(key) {
          return snapshot.val()[key];
        });
        return users;
      });
  }
```

Or alternately, if you need that wrapping Promise you need to resolve it with the return value:

```
pullFromFirebase = (displayedUser) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + displayedUser.id + '/usersLiked/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        const users = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(function(key) {
          return snapshot.val()[key];
        })
        resolve(users);
      });
    })
  }
```